# for loop appears to not be running at all

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I understand there's better ways to be doing what I'm doing, but I'm genuinely confused to why the for loop isn't running at all.

```js
function intArray(x) {
  let a = x.toString();
  let b = a.split("");
  return b;
}

function digitalRoot(n) {
  var b = intArray(n);
  console.log(b);
  let d = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i > b.length; i++) {
    d += parseInt(b[i]);
    console.log("for loop doing anything?");
  }
  return d;
}
// Desired output (for now):28
let testNumber = 73279;
console.log(digitalRoot(testNumber));
```

Comment: double check your looping condition: `i > b.length`

Comment: Your loop runs only if `i > b.length`, that is, if the array has a negative length.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like an idiot now for not seeing that lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for loop is wrong. It should be "less than" not "greater than" since you start from zero up to the length of your array

```js
function intArray(x) {
  let a = x.toString();
  let b = a.split("");
  return b;
}

function digitalRoot(n) {
  var b = intArray(n);
  console.log(b);
  let d = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { // <- HERE
    d += parseInt(b[i]);
    console.log("for loop doing anything?");
  }
  return d;
}
// Desired output (for now):28
let testNumber = 73279;
console.log(digitalRoot(testNumber));
```

Comment: I took the liberty to turn your code into a runnable snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
function intArray(x) {
  return x.toString().split("");
}

function digitalRoot(n) {
  var b = intArray(n);
  let d = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    d += parseInt(b[i]);
  }
  return d;
}

// Desired output (for now):28
let testNumber = 73279;
console.log(digitalRoot(testNumber));
```